# How to read decimal value from the XML response in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I want to read values from below response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
  <ConversionRateResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
     <ConversionRateResult>59.565</ConversionRateResult>
  </ConversionRateResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have tried below code to get the value as 59.565, but I am getting NULL:

```
def Xml = new XmlHolder(response)
def String rate = Xml.getNodeValue('//ConversionRateResponse/ConversionRateResult')
log.info(rate)
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you don't need to do `def String rate`, just `String rate` will do`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText( response )
String rate = xml.Body.ConversionRateResponse.ConversionRateResult.text()
```